# How do I clear Console (Java)? Notepad++

Tags: java, console, notepad++, javac, nppexec

I have looked through some questions of the similar name, none yielding the desired results. Here's an overview of my issue.

I use both `println()` and `print()` statements for Notepad++, and the console is `System.out`. I tried working with `System.out.flush()`, but I don't believe it is the function that I am looking for.

My main objective is to delete all the previous printed information, so updated information can be **reprinted** in its stead. I seen some solutions like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

but that didn't take into account the size of the console, which could vary by computer and by user adjusted sizes.

Thus, the most effective way is to somehow delete the code. I looked into `Runtime` and `"cls"`, along with many of the other various methods (ANSI) that were offered in other solutions, which makes me believe that using Notepad++ has its own unique ways of clearing the console.

Another unforeseen possibility is that there is some way to update the displayed String, in which case knowing how to do that would be very helpful. As far as I know, there's no way of doing so.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is to use System.setOut and use another printstream that prints to something you can clear, like a textarea

Comment: There is no indication that Notepad++ has a way to clear the console (from within the application) at all…

Comment: So I figured. I have resorted to using JavaFX

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
```

**Note:** Only works for CMD If you use IDE then not, Because command `cls` is of Windows command prompt and IDE is not command prompt and even if you use Linux OS or some other the Windows OS then also it was not work.

Comment: That's what I figured when I saw it. I'm using Notepad++, so it's not quite applicable

Comment: Then the way you are using is best one...!